# What is determining the height of these html tags?

Tags: html, css

Considering the below 2 code snippets, how the `html` height is calculated?

---

**1** In Chrome, `html`s height is `20px`.

```css
body {
  margin: 8px;
}

div {
  margin: 10px;
  display: flow-root;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My first thought was it's because making `div` into a block-formatting-context (BFC) suppresses its margin-collapsing (so `div` has a total vertical margin of 20px).

---

**2** However, if that's the case, I wouldn't know how to explain why `html`'s height is `19px` here:

```css
body {
  margin: 8px;
  height: 1px;
}

div {
  margin: 10px;
  display: flow-root;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm really confused as to why this is a bad question. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: actually it's a very intresting question ;)

Comment: @tonitone120 this is the type of question that you should be asking. It has code and a clearly defined issue. As Temani said, it is an interesting question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first case you go it correctly, the margin of the div will collapse with all the body margins (top and bottom) and only `20px` will remain which will define the final height of the html

For the second case, the height of the body will disable the bottom margin collapsing so at the end you will have the top margin 10px (the result of the collapse between 8px and 10px) then the bottom margin of the div will not collapse with the bottom margin of the body BUT will overflow since you defined an explicit height (this is the tricky part) so 8px of margin will be considered in the bottom and will define the height of the html which give us the total of `10px + 1px + 8px = 19px`. In other words, it's like the bottom margin of the div is not defined.

Comment: So the fact that `body`'s height is > 0 means margin-collapsing does not occur between its child (`div`)'s margin-bottom and its margin-bottom. Where does this margin go? I would've expected the 10px would make `body` bigger. But of course it can't because we've already defined `body` to be `1px`. So it's essentially disregarded for now?

Comment: @tonitone120 yes, such margin collapsing occur only when the height is set to auto. This margin exist but will have no effect since you set the height so you will have an overflow. It's difficult to *see* it since it's a space but it's there.

Comment: 1. Okay, but will this 10px over-flowing margin potentially interact with anything else? 2. I hope it's not too cheeky but I appended a third snippet to the question just to hammer home this point about margins. Now `body` is also a BFC. For example, `html` `height` is `17px` and I presume this is because  `div`'s margin-top doesn't collpase with `body`'s margin-top

Comment: @tonitone120 (1) no it won't, it's an overflow and margin aren't part of the element so we cannot consider the fact that it can overlap something else (2) yes, now you have 20px of margin overflowing and the total for the html will be 8 + 8 + 1 = 17

Comment: From this question I’ve learnt: 1. For an element with BFC, its vertical margins will not collapse with one another. Thanks very much you've been very useful. Can you recommend a website to find out great findings like this that isn't the 'spec' (I find it too hard to read right now) or MDN? Have a good day

Comment: @tonitone120 I would recommend not trying to find such things because they never end. You will face them while practising and you learn them. Better focus on learning how to use HTML/CSS to do stuffs than trying to find such tricky cases (you will forget them if you don't practise)

Comment: Fair enough - I will create!